# Parser for XLSX is not installed at ./aa.pl line 44

Tags: perl

I am trying to Parse my XLSX files in my perl program. where I have Installed Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, please refer below:

```
(tc-lab-04) /home/trustid/switchadaptor/testauto/dataverificationtesting2/XL_Parsing>sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"'

[sudo] password for a597549: 

Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'

Database was generated on Thu, 26 May 2022 05:29:03 GMT
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel is up to date (0.65)
```

But when I am trying to run my Program or my tool it is still showing me the below error:

```
Parser for XLSX is not installed at ./aa.pl line 44
```

The command I have used to install the `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` is --`sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"'`.

I already tried to install it again but it never helps me.

Comment: To parse XLSX, please try [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX)

Comment: An easier command is `sudo cpan Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`

Answer (score 2):

Like the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#DESCRIPTION) for that module says:

> The Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module can be used to read information from Excel 95-2003 binary files.
>
> The module cannot read files in the Excel 2007 Open XML XLSX format. See the Spreadsheet::XLSX module instead.

Comment: thanks, I was having trouble using `Spreadsheet::Read`, problem solved without changing any code by doing `cpan install Spreadsheet::XLSX`.